# Setting Delegate and Lazy instantiation

Tags: objective-c, macos, delegates

I have an App with an `NSWindowController` and an associated XIB which is not needed most of the time (admin interface window), so I wanted to use Lazy instantiation. However, I also need to setup the 'delegate' and that is when the errors happen.

I have everything setup in the AdminWindow,h (subclass of `NSWindowController') and .m file.

In my main controller, MainController (subclass of `NSObject`) I have the following working code.

```
@interface MainController : NSObject<AdminWindowDelegate>{
   AdminWindow *myAdminWindow;
}

@implementation MainController

-(id)init{
  myAdminWindow = [[AdminWindow alloc] init];
  [myAdminWindow setDelegate:self];

}

-(IBAction)openAdminWindow:(id)sender{

 [myAdminWindow showWindow:nil];
}
```

So that all works, but I don't want to instantiate myAdminWindow until it's needed, thought lazy instantiation would work.

Altered the MainController:

```
 @implementation{

 -(AdminWindow *) myAdminWindow{

 if(!_myAdminWindow){

 _myAdminWindow = [[AdminWindow alloc] init];

 //Tried to set delegate here, but does not work

}

-(IBAction)openAdminWindow:(id)sender{

 [self.myAdminWindow showWindow:nil];
}
```

Where do I set the delegate? I tried just after 'alloc' 'init' of myAdminWindow, but it does not work. when I start typing the command

```
 _myAdminWindow.setDe...  Xcode gives nothing, .setDelegate or .delegate are not options.
```

I've tried

```
 [_myAdminWindow setDelegate   Nope, does not work either.
```

Leaving out the delegate portion, everything else works as desired.

Question: When using lazy instantiation , where do I set the delegate? and how?

Thank you in advance

===[EDIT]===

In case someone else has the same question.

Thank you to Phillip Mills for the reply and reminder.

I removed the following declaration in `@interface` of `MainController`:

```
 AdminWindow *myAdminWindow;
```

And declared `myAdminWindow` in the `MainController`'s `interface` section as a `property` - and all is good!

Comment: What's your declaration of `_myAdminWindow` look like?  Have you changed `myAdminWindow` into a property?

Comment: Duh - I was declaring it in the `interface` as above(`AdminWindow* myAdminWindow;`), not as a `property`. I changed it and declared it as a `property` and that worked - thank you.

Comment: Glad to help.  I'm surprised that it even got past `if(!_myAdminWindow)` without an error.